# Vue3 Composition API watcher firing immediately but it should be lazy

Tags: jquery-select2, watch, vuejs3

According to vue3 [docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-computed-watchers.html#watch), the watcher should be lazy by default and yet mine is triggered immediately.
I have a parent form where i make an axios request to retrieve a list of categories from db, then i send them as prop data to a child select2 input ( yes, the jquery one ).

**ParentForm.vue:**

```html
<template>
 <VSelect2 :data="categories" @item-added="getCategories()"/>
</template>
<script>
export default {
 name: "Form",
 setup() {
    let categories = ref([])
    const getCategories = async () => {
      const response = await httpClient.get('/api/categories')
      response.data.forEach(category => {
        categories.value.push({
          id: category.id,
          text: category.title,
        })
      })
    }
    getCategories()
    return {
      categories
    }
 }
}
</script>
```

**VSelect2.vue:**

```html
<template>
 <select
    class="vue-select2"
  >
</template>
<script>
import {
  onMounted,
  watch
} from 'vue'
export default {
 name: "VSelect2",
 props: {
   data: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
 },
 setup(props) {
    onMounted(() => {
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.vue-select2').select2({
          multiple: true,
          tags: true,
          allowClear: true,
          tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
          data: props.data,
        }).on('select2:select', function (event) {
              //when user adds an item, make a post request then emit event for the parent to retrieve the new data
              ...
              emit('item-added')
        })
     })
    })

    watch(props.data, (newValue) => {
      console.log(newValue)
    })

    return {
    }
 }
}
</script>
```

There is an issue on [github](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/issues/671) and it says that's the intended behaviour but the docs say otherwise... i'm a bit confused. Does anyone know if i can set this to lazy somehow? Passing `{immediate: false}` or `{lazy:true}` as watch options does nothing...

Comment: can you clarify what is making you believe that watch is behaving in a "non-lazy way"? `watch` _applies side effects in a separate callback function. It also is lazy by default - i.e. the callback is only called when the watched source has changed._ whereas `watchEffect`  _Runs a function immediately while reactively tracking its dependencies and re-runs it whenever the dependencies are changed_

Comment: @Daniel, the fact that in vue2 it didn't trigger the callback on initial load if you didn't specify the `immediate` option, as is the case with this github issue (https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/issues/671). Isn't that what lazy means? Don't do anything yet due to the fact that of course a prop will receive some data at first so don't act until the next time it changes?

Answer (score 1):

Well I am not able to reproduce what you say here. Look at the simple example below. The `watch` callback is called only once when the value changes (after 2 seconds to simulate the async call) - **it is lazy**

```js
const App = {
  template: '<comp :data="categories"></comp>',
  setup() {
    let categories = Vue.ref([])
    const getCategories = async() => {
      return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
        categories.value.push({
          name: "Category A"
        })
        resolve()
      }, 2000));
    }
    getCategories()

    return {
      categories
    }
  }
}

const app = Vue.createApp(App)

app.component('comp', {
  props: {
    data: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  },
  template: `<h4>{{ data }}</h4>`,
  setup(props) {
    Vue.watch(props.data, (newValue) => {
      console.log("New value:", newValue)
    })

    return {}
  }
})

app.mount("#app")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.0.7/vue.global.js" integrity="sha512-+i5dAv2T8IUOP7oRl2iqlAErpjtBOkNtREnW/Te+4VgQ52h4tAY5biFFQJmF03jVDWU4R7l47BwV8H6qQ+/MfA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

As to a linked GH [issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/issues/671) - you should be very careful with all info shared as part of the issue reported for pre-release version ("alpha 4" in this case). If you read whole discussion, you will find that this issue led to a creation of new [RFC](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/pull/125) and as a result of the discussion, they later changed the behavior described in the issue so that `watch` lazy evaluation was kept to be compatible with Vue 2 (from the perspective of the issue, that was change author requested) and new API `watchEffect` was introduced (which is "eager")

Vue 3 is now released so official documentation should be your main source of information, not GH issue for very outdated pre-release version...

Comment: I'm not sure, it might be a conflict with the select2 jquery plugin, since that's what i'm using in my child component. Sometimes, when the api fetch takes longer due to cache invalidation on back end, the child component gets rendered without props.data even though i have a v-if="data" on the child, in parent component. Probably that's why i get the feeling that the watcher gets triggered on initial load when in fact, it gets loaded with an empty data, then the promise fulfil and the watcher gets triggered.

Comment: Using jQuery with something so different as Vue is questionable. I hope you think about how to [prevent memory leaks](https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)
Anyway, the question wasn't about Vue vs jQuery interaction but about `watch` laziness. Hope my answer made it clear....